# Create/modify Meteor templates at runtime

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am wondering how to solve this problem:

I have a template which contains some text with some template helpers inside:

```
<template>Hello {{who}}, the wheather is {{weather}}</template>
```

Now I need to change the content of the template dynamically at runtime, while maintaining the helper functionality. For example I would need it like this:

```
<template>Oh, the {{weather}}. Good evening {{who}}</template>
```

The text changes and the helpers are needed at different positions. Think of an application where users can create custom forms with placeholders for certain variables like the name of the user who fills out the form. Basically, the content of the template is stored in a mongo document and needs to be turned into a template at runtime, or an existing template needs to be changed.

How to approach this? Can I change the contents of a template at runtime?

Comment: Can the content of the template always be expressed as a string like your example, or could it contain other html elements, sub-templates, etc.?

Comment: In my use case it could contain text and html, but no subtemplates. No dynamic stuff except the helpers.

Comment: Have you tried Server Side Rendering?, that might be a good way to go.    On the client, it is possible to create templates at runtime doing something like this https://github.com/looshi/Meteor-Live-Template-Editor/blob/master/client/views/template-editor/Editor.js#L227.  I don't know how to assign scoped helpers to the templates though, only globally scoped helpers.  here is a working demo, you can edit these templates at runtime http://live-template-editor.meteor.com/FjkeyHE94KvooDHeS   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this use case you need to use two techniques.

Firstly you need to be able to change the template reactivel. To do this you can use `Template.dynamic`. eg:

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=helperToReturnName [data=data] }}
```

See here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic

Now that you can change template, you need to be able to create new templates on the fly from you database content. This is non trivial, but it's possible if you're willing to write code to create them, like this:

```
Template.__define__("postList", (function() {
  var view = this;
  return [
    HTML.Raw("<h1>Post List</h1>\n  "),
    HTML.UL("\n    ", Blaze.Each(function() {
      return Spacebars.call(view.lookup("posts"));
    },
    function() {
      return [ "\n      ", HTML.LI(Blaze.View(function() {
        return Spacebars.mustache(view.lookup("title"));
      })), "\n    " ];
    }), "\n  ")
  ];
}));
```

That code snippet was taken from [this article](https://meteorhacks.com/how-blaze-works.html) on Meteorhacks, and the article itself goes into far more detail. After reading the article you'll be armed with the knowledge you need to complete the task...

Answer (score 0):

Just have a helper dynamically build the entire string (remembering that *this* refers to the current data context):

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  dynamicString: function(switch){
    if ( switch == 1) return "Hello "+this.who+", the wheather is "+this.weather;
    else return "Oh, the "+this.weather+". Good evening "+this.who;
  }
});
```

Then in your template:

```
<template name="foo">
  {{dynamicString}}
</template>
```

Alternatively, just use {{#if variable}} or {{#unless variable}} blocks to change the logic in your template. Much, much simpler.

```
<template name="foo">
  {{#if case1}}
    Hello {{who}}, the wheather is {{weather}}
  {{else}}
    Oh, the {{weather}}. Good evening {{who}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

You can always have a template helper that computes the necessary boolean variables (e.g. *case1*).

Comment: But who and weather are not in the context, they are helpers of the template.